# installing mysql innodb engine on redhat box

Tags: mysql, redhat, innodb

I'm using SL6.1 on an X86-64 server box.

For whatever reasons, it looks like the stock RHEL-anything is not going to be including the mysql innodb engine anytime in the foreseeable future:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=740224

Any thoughts on how to get innodb functionality short of compiling from scratch?

thx

Answer (score 0):

The innodb plugin is an alternate provider of the built in InnoDB engine. It is not required to use InnoDB tables, it merely provides some additional features above and beyond the built in InnoDB engine.

The versions of MySQL in RHEL are fully InnoDB capable with the built in InnoDB engine.